# How to update data for all symbols in amibroker

Tags: c#, .net, amibroker

I am using the .Net SDK for making a real-time data plugin.

https://github.com/kriasoft/amibroker

The logic for GetQuotesEx() has be added, it updates the data for that symbol when a symbol chart is opened in Amibroker.

I need a bit of help in what steps should I follow to get real time data, I have been trying to figure this out since a week.

Currently I know that
I have to call NotifyStreamingUpdate() from somewhere when the data is ready.   but for which ticker will Amibroker call this function for?
I am new to C#, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In GetQuotesEx, there's a parameter, ticker. That's the ticker calling for data. So you can use that to search the datasource. I, for example, have text files with the ticker in the filename, so I'll search for the filename containing the ticker and load that data.